# PHP Regex get reverse number

Tags: php, regex

i have this:

```
$pattern = 'dev/25{LASTNUMBER}/P/{YYYY}'
$var = 'dev/251/P/2014'
```

in this situation {LASTNUMBER} = 1 how to get this from $var

vars in pattern can by more always in {}

pattern can by different example :

```
 $pattern = '{LASTNUMBER}/aa/bb/P/{OtherVar}'
```

in this situation var will by 1/aa/bb/p/some and want get 1

I need get {LASTNUMBER} have pattern and have results

Ok maybe is not possible :) or very very hard

Comment: Your question isn't clear... What are trying to achieve? Could you be more explicit?

Comment: preg_match_all has a $matches argument which stores the values found with parenthesis in your regex. that's what you want, I think.

Answer (score 3):

use a regex..

```
if (preg_match('~dev/25([0-9])/P/[0-9]{4}~', $var, $m)) {
    $lastnum = $m[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = explode("/", $pattern);
if (isset($parts[1])) {
    return substr($parts[1], -1);
}
```

will be faster than regex :)

Comment: Yeah, but you are not sure, if the given input has the correct format

Comment: @Philipp true, but "Grek Hmhmm" didnt said that this is required

Answer (score 0):

You probably need this:

```
<?php
$pattern = 'dev/251/P/2014';
preg_match_all('%dev/25(.*?)/P/[\d]{4}%sim', $pattern, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$match = $match[1][0];
echo $match; // echo's 1
?>
```

Check it [online](http://ideone.com/vsQFNr)

If you need to loop trough results you can use:

```
<?php
$pattern = <<< EOF
dev/251/P/2014
dev/252/P/2014
dev/253/P/2014
dev/254/P/2014
dev/255/P/2014
EOF;

preg_match_all('%dev/25(.*?)/P/[\d]{4}%sim', $pattern , $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($match[1]); $i++) {
    echo  $match[1][$i]; //echo's 12345
}
?>
```

Check in [online](http://ideone.com/JMz4u7)

Comment: whats the adventage of preg_match_all instead of simply preg_match?